# Proving Convergence of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a_{n})$ be a sequence in $[0,\infty)$ and assume that a sequence $(a_{n})$ converges to $a$. Use
the $\epsilon$, $N$ definition of convergence, prove that if $a \geq 0$ then $lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{a_{n}} =\sqrt{a}$.
(Hint: treat the cases $a = 0$ and $a > 0$ separately.)

How exactly do I pick an $N$? Not really sure how to get started. Thanks

Comment: Hint: Try to first show that $(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{a_n})^2 \le |a - a_n|$

Answer (score 0):

The direct way to start, is "let be $\epsilon>0$". Now, you want to show that if $n>N$, then $\sqrt{a}-\epsilon<\sqrt{a_n}<\sqrt{a}+\epsilon$. Assuming $a>0$ (for now), $\epsilon$ can be small enough, such that $\sqrt a>\epsilon$. Hence, the above inequality involves only positive numbers, and we can square it: $(\sqrt{a}-\epsilon)^2<a_n<(\sqrt{a}+\epsilon)^2$.
Now, clearly $(\sqrt{a}-\epsilon)^2<a<(\sqrt{a}+\epsilon)^2$, so we can fix a $\delta=min\{a-(\sqrt{a}-\epsilon)^2,(\sqrt{a}+\epsilon)^2-a\}$ (so that $(\sqrt{a}-\epsilon)^2<a-\delta<a+\delta<(\sqrt{a}+\epsilon)^2$  ), and since $a_n\rightarrow a$, there is an $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $a-\delta<a_n<a+\delta$. take **that** $N$, and if you read the last 2 paragraphs backward, you have a proof.

The case $a=0$ is similar (take $\delta=\sqrt\epsilon$). a cannot be negative, since in this case, we can take $\epsilon=-\frac a 2$, and thus, for large $n$, $a_n<a+\epsilon=\frac a 2<0$.

Answer (score 0):

(1) You don't need to explicitly pick an $N$. You got the $N$ freely from what you are given: the sequence $a_n$ converges.

That is, by given we have for all $\epsilon$ there exist an $N$ that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ for $n\geq N $

Suppose $a<0$ then since $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n$, an epsilon of value $a$ would never be satisfied as $|a_n-a|=a_n-a\geq 0-a=a$ contradicting our given.

(2)

If $a=0$, then  for any $\epsilon$ we have an $N$ that $|a_n|<\epsilon$ for $n\geq N$. Hence for any $\epsilon$ let $\epsilon_2=\epsilon^2$ there exist an $M$ that $|a_n|<\epsilon_2$ for $n\geq M$. Hence for all $\epsilon$ the same $M$ would give $|\sqrt{a_n}|<\epsilon$ for $n\geq M$.

If $a\neq 0$, we have $|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{a}|=|\large{a_n-a\over\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{a}}|<|\large{a_n-a\over\sqrt{a}}|$. By given we have for any $\epsilon$ there exist an $N$ that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ for $n\geq N$. Hence for any $\epsilon$ define $\epsilon_2=\epsilon\sqrt{a}$ then there exist an $M$ such that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon_2$ for $n\geq M$. Hence for all $\epsilon$ we have the same $M$ that $|\large{a_n-a\over\sqrt{a}}|<\epsilon$.